# MonetDB multi thread support

Tags: .net, odbc, monetdb

I use MonetDB in my .net project via odbc driver.

Does monetDB support multi thread insert, update, delete via odbc?
When I tried to test it I have got ODBCException: general exception.

How does MonetDB handles concurrent requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for information about concurrency control.  Especially the
second section.
https://www.monetdb.org/blog/monetdb-sql-transaction-management-scheme